# Weka classifier model in map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, weka

I have written a map reduce code to emit csv values from map and the reducer creates the weka instances and builds a classifier. How to save the classifier so that my next map reduce job will pick up this model and run it on a test data to predict a value?

Map:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Get csv values
        context.write(csv values);
}
```

Reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Create instances with all the csv values
        Classifier classifier = new NaiveBayes();
        try {
            classifier.buildClassifier(trainingSet);
            context.write(classifier,
                    NullWritable.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

How do I read this file in the next map reduce task so that it doesnt read line by line and I am able to build the classifier object by reading the file?

Or is there any other way to achieve this?